Why sampling from the posterior is a good estimate for the Likelihood but sampling from the prior is bad?
In Variational Autoencoders (VAE), we have:
$$
\log p_\theta(x) = \log \left[ \int p_\theta(x \mid z)p(z) \, dz \right]
$$
where $ p_\theta(x \mid z) = \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_\theta(z), I) $ and $ p(z) = \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. When deriving the Evidence Lower Bound (ELBO), by Jensen's equality, we obtain:
$$
\log p_\theta(x) \geq \int \log [p_\theta(x \mid z)] p(z) \, dz
$$
This integral is claimed to be hard to estimate since $z$ is high-dimensional. However, by using importance sampling and the variational distribution $q_\phi(z \mid x)$, the ELBO becomes:
$$
\log p_\theta(x) \geq \int \log [p_\theta(x \mid z)] q_\phi(z \mid x) \, dz - \text{KL}(q_\phi(z \mid x) \parallel p(z))
$$
The Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence has a closed form since $ q_\phi(z \mid x) = \mathcal{N}(z; \mu_\phi(x), \sigma_\phi(x) I) $. This is supposed to make the estimation tractable. How is this possible? $p(z) $ and $q_\phi(z \mid x)$ are Gaussian distributions and easy to sample from. I guess it all boils down to the number of samples needed to estimate the integral. I assume it is a must that $L_2\gg L_1$ to have a similar accuracy? If this is the case, why is it the case?
$$
\mathbb{E}_{q_\phi(x|z)} [p_\theta(x|z)] \approx \frac{1}{L_1} \sum_{l=1}^{L_1} \log p_\theta(x \mid z^{(l)}), \quad z^{(l)} \sim q_\phi(z \mid x) \rightarrow \text{Good estimate?}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(z)} [p_\theta(x|z)] \approx \frac{1}{L_2} \sum_{l=1}^{L_2} \log p_\theta(x \mid z^{(l)}), \quad z^{(l)} \sim p(z) \rightarrow \text{Bad estimate?}
$$

Does this recent post answer the necessity of the posterior in VI/VAE for you? Keep in mind the likelihood of data $p(x)$ is intractable, thus only the variational KL-divergence or equivalently the ELBO objective can be tractably and approximately addressed in a hopeful manner, sometimes VI would collapse the posterior to the prior with bad weights.

@cinch I have heavily edited the question

You're using amortized inference with additional mean-field assumption here and you don't know the explicit form of $\mu_\phi$ and $\sigma_\phi$, how can you claim it's easy to sample from even you've assumed a MVN distribution? VAEs belong to explicit likelihood parametric methods family, so usually it's not mainly using sampling but (joint) optimization to hopefully arrive at some 'optimal' value for variational parameters $\phi,\theta$.

It is indeed, as you say, because sampling from the prior would require many, many samples to achieve the same accuracy.
Note that you need to evaluate these integrals for a given value of $x$. If both the data and the latent space are sufficiently high-dimensional, then if we just sample "willy-nilly" from $p(z)$, any one given realization of $x$ is very unlikely for most choices of $z$.
To make this more concrete, let's say that $x$ is a photograph of a face, and $z$ is a descriptor of all the factors that make up a face (e.g. spacing between the eyes, curvature of the mouth, width of each eyebrow, and so on). We have a database of such photographs, and we want to calculate the probability of the data in this database given some model (to evaluate how good this model is), by integrating over all possible $z$'s that could have led to this data. For any one face photograph $x$, its probability conditioned on $z$ is essentially 0 unless we choose the values of $z$ just right. For instance, if the entry for $z$ that encodes hair color is set to "brown", and the face in the picture is a blonde, then $p(x|z)\approx0$. If the face in the picture has dark skin, but the relevant entry in $z$ is set to light skin, then $p(x|z)\approx0$. And so on. And because $z$ is high-dimensional, it is exceedingly unlikely that we ever get all its values right, or sufficiently close, so that we avoid $p(x|z)\approx0$ - it just takes one value being wrong, and we're screwed.
Why is it bad that $p(x|z)\approx0$? Well, first of all, it may lead to numerical instability, if probabilities become so small as to be numerically equal to 0, or log probabilities so small as to be numerically equal to $-
\infty$. But more fundamentally: the integral we are trying to approximate depends heavily on those regions where $p(x|z)$ is meaningfully different from 0. If we only take samples of $z$ for which $p(x|z)\approx0$, then our estimate will be very inaccurate.
So, instead, we would like to focus on those regions in latent space where $p(x|z)$ is meaningfully different from 0, i.e. where the observed data is probably given its hypothesized causes. This is, in general, the motivation for importance sampling: focus on those regions of the distribution that are (as the name implies) most important to the accuracy of the answer, and then apply a correction factor afterwards to compensate for this biased sampling.
How you choose your sampling distribution is often quite tricky in importance sampling, but with VAEs we are in luck, because we already have a machine for us that can, pretty quickly, spit out an approximation to the posterior $p(z|x)$ for any given $x$. And one thing we know about the posterior is that it concentrates its probability on those values of $z$ that are likely given the data. In the absence of a strong prior, this also implies that $p(x|z)$ will typically be high as well, for values of $z$ where $p(z|x)$ is high. So, sampling from $q(z|x)$ is very likely to allow us to concentrate on the important regions of $p(x,z)$, and thus get an accurate estimate of the marginal likelihood with relatively few samples.

Thank you. You said that $p(x|z)$ would typically be high for values of $z$ where $p(z|x)$ is high in the absence of strong prior. That is not the case of VAE since the prior is zero-mean diagonal-covariance Gaussian. Although $z$ is highly dimensional, we have restricted the values of $z$ by introducing the KL divergence. Your example of faces is spot on, but under the condition that there is no regularization on the space of $z$. Do you agree?

By "strong prior", I meant something extreme enough to overrule the likelihood. That's not normally the case in VAEs. If you sample $z^*\sim q(z|x)$ and then project this back through the decoder, you'll usually get something back that is close to the input $x$ (e.g. an image similar to the handwritten digit you put in). So this tells you that the likelihood dominates the inference, and  most any $z$ sampled from $q(z|x)$ will lead to high $p(x|z)$.

(To relate this back to the faces example: it's (typically) not the case that we have such a strong prior that despite a face clearly having green eyes, we'll get a $q(z|x)$ that puts low probability on green eyes and high probability on brown eyes. At most, our approximate posterior will be a very slight biased towards brown eyes. That is, of course, unless you're evaluating your model in an out-of-distribution setting, with test data sampled from a markedly different distribution from what the VAE was trained on.)
